# Alfresco giving same search result on each page

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Whenever I search for a content in alfresco, suppose there are 250 result found, the 1,2,3 etc pages are showing the same file instead of 250 different files.

[image: Page1 of search result]
[image: Page2 of search result]

Sorry I cant show the file name. I think the image and the modified result is enough to show. How to fix this ?

I am using alfresco 4.2 e binary installer.

**I found the root cause of the problem. It is because I used this [fix](http://www.contentreich.de/alfresco-share-search-and-drop-in-fix). Since alfresco search two words using `or` rather than `and`. I removed the javascript and now its working fine.**

Comment: What specific version of Alfresco are you using and have you made any customizations? Did you install with the binary installer or manually? Are you using Lucene or Solr?

Comment: I am using 4.2e binary installer. I think 4.2 e uses solr

Comment: @JeffPotts I did some ui customization. Other than that I didnt customize any basic functionality. Will rebuilding index help?

Comment: @JeffPotts I found the cause of the problem. Thankyou